# Авторизация гостя без регистрации ASP.NET CORE

Tags: asp.net-core

Есть интернет магазин и я хочу чтобы пользователь отправил товар в корзину и далее совершил покупку. Конечно же чтобы хранить данные корзины пользователя в бд нужно как то пользователя запомнить НО я хочу обойтись без регистрации и чтобы пользователь запомнился на время. Разные колеса в голову приходят но я понимаю что это или глупо или не безопасно. Посоветуйте пожалуйста  как  реализовать это на ASP.NET CORE (хоть простой вопрос но не смог ответ найти, простите)